# Dynamically allocating work to pthreads via a queue

Tags: c, pthreads

Okay, so I'm having an issue with dynamically allocating work to pthreads in a queue.

For example, in my code I have a struct like below:

```
struct calc
{
    double num;
    double calcVal;
};
```

I store each struct in an array of length l like below.

```
struct calc **calcArray; 

/* then I initialize the calcArray to say length l and 
   fill each calc struct with a num*/
```

Now, based on num, I want to find the value of calcVal. Each struct calc has a different value for num.

I want to spawn 4 pthreads which is easy enough but I want to make it so at the start,

thread 0 gets calcArray[0]
thread 1 gets calcArray[1]
thread 2 gets calcArray[2]
thread 3 gets calcArray[3]

Now assuming that it will take different times for each thread to do the calculations for each calc,

if thread 1 finishes first, it will then get calcArray[4]

then thread 3 finishes and gets calcArray[5] to do

and this continues until it reaches the end of calcArray[l].

I know I could just split the array into l/4 (each thread gets one quarter of the calcs) but I don't want to do this. Instead I want to make the work like a queue. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could accomplish it pretty easily, by creating a variable containing the index of the next element to be assigned, and then having it secured by a mutex.

Example:

```
// Index of next element to be worked on
int next_pos;

// Mutex that secures next_pos-access
pthread_mutex_t next_pos_lock;

int main() {
    // ...

    // Initialize the mutex before you create any threads 
    pthread_mutex_init(&next_pos_lock, NULL);

    next_pos = NUM_THREADS;

    // Create the threads

    // ...
}

void *threadfunc(void *arg) {
    int index = ...;

    while (index < SIZE_OF_WORK_ARRAY) {
        // Do your work

        // Update your index
        pthread_mutex_lock(&next_pos_lock);
        index = next_pos;
        next_pos++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&next_pos_lock);
    }
}
```

See also: [POSIX Threads Programming - Mutex Variables](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#Mutexes)

Comment: There are typos in this comment! It says "phread" instead of "pthread"! Took me a long time to discover...

Comment: You're suggesting a busy waiting approach, no?

Comment: How does this ensure that the threads will run after each other? I feel like, it will run it on a single thread throughout the program, because we aren't directing the threads at the function.